# What is “(program)” in Chrome debugger’s profiler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

What is “(program)” in the function column of the Chrome debugger?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`(program)` is Chrome itself, the root of the tree calling all other code...it's there because the jump from native code to JavaScript, resource loading, etc. has to start *somewhere* :)

You can see examples of the treeview [in the Chrome developer tool docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution).

Comment: ah -- so if thats a high percent, is there anything i can do about it?

Comment: @hvgotcodes - It sound be the percentage of all portions below.  Now if the *self* percentage is high, there's not much you can do....unless your markup in general is very heavy.

Comment: Do you, please, know how to access code in the "(program)" section? Somehow parts of JavaScript in project I'm currently working on do end up there, and the only way I can get there in debugger is by placing "debugger;" into the code, which is not quite comfortable.

Comment: I think this is actually wrong and @user1009908's answer is correct. Its not the root, its native code. The is supported by the fact that the tree view example don't show it as the root.

Comment: @studgeek it's the root of the tree as far as *your code* is concerned in almost every case - very, very rarely is there a js -> native -> js transition, that's what I meant here and I think it's fairly clear...I state pretty clearly that it's native code.

Comment: Regarding high % of program(), sometimes css animations lead to a high CPU usage, which will be reflected in program(). Unfortunately the profiler can't help pin point the source.

Answer (score 33):

I believe (program) is native code, not the root of the tree.

See this thread:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88446

So, more like system calls than like main().

Apparently it includes idle time. Also, some profiling of (program) is available from chrome://profiler/

Comment: Agreed - but just an update: it doesn't include idle time anymore. That's now being reported separately as (idle)

Answer (score 15):

As @Nick says, it has to start somewhere.

It looks like the CPU Profiler part is like so many other profilers that are based on the [same concepts as gprof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).

For example, *self* is nearly a useless number unless there is something like a bubble-sort of a big array of numbers in some code that you can edit. Highly unlikely.

*Total* should include callees, so that's more useful. However, unless samples are taken during blocked time as well as during running time, it is still pretty useless except for totally cpu-bound programs.

It gives you these stats by function, rather than by line of code. That means (if you could rely on *Total* percent) that a function costs that much, in the sense that if you could somehow make it take zero time, such as by stubbing it, that percent is how much time you would save.

So if you want to focus on a costly function, you need to hunt inside it for what could be optimized. In order to do that, you need to know how the time is subdivided among the lines of code in the function. If you had cost on a line of code basis, it would take you directly to those lines.

I don't know if you will be able to get a better profiler, like a wall-clock stack sampler reporting at the line level, such as [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/). Here's [how I do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Comment: @hvgotcodes: Not sure. I don't use them, because I just take stackshots in a debugger. But you're on Linux, right? Can you get a trial copy of Zoom? It's pretty good.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: Well then, the only help I can offer is the method I rely on.