# Meaning of JavaScript idle time which is long time in Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-performance

What is the meaning of JavaScript idle time in Chrome Developer tools?
I got a very long idle time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idle time is the time in which nothing is done.

You can check a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702940/what-does-idle-mean-in-google-chrome-devtools-profiler) in which Rob W has answerd it.

> Go to `about:blank`, and get a new CPU profile. The result is probably a
>   value for (idle) close to 100% and a bit of (program)